# Error when trying to import a class in a script in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I just made a class in Python3 and wanted to import it into an other script.

Both files are in the same folder btw.

```
# myclass.py

import sys
import networkx as nx

class MyClass:
...
```

And my script look like this:

```
# myscript.py

import os
from collections import defaultdict
from myclass import MyClass
...
```

And when I try to execute `myscript.py`I got a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named networkx`. Do you know how I should import my class into my script ?

EDIT: The module called networkx is installed, in fact every non-builtin module I import in the `myclass.py` raise this error

Comment: `pip install networkx`

Comment: well there is no module called `networkx`. If you try to run `myclass.py` you'll get the same error. It's nothing to do with import myclass into myscript.

Comment: I should I written in the post that the module networkx is already installed on my system; I edited the post

Comment: Then the module is probably incorrectly installed, Python import machinery cannot find it. How did you install it? Are you using virtual environment? Are you using Anaconda?

Comment: I used pip3 install for it and i'm not using a virtual env;
EDIT: I have no issue importing the module itself in other scripts, I just created a file to test and the module is imported and I can work with it

Comment: What is the output of `pip3 --freeze`? Are you sure you are running your script using `python3` and not just `python` 2.7?

Comment: You got it right ! I actually have both python 3.5 and 3.6 installed, I was using the wrong one. Thanks !

Comment: Great news then. :)